# Guardar archivos adjuntos Django desde un formulario

Tags: django, django-forms, fileupload

Estoy realizando una aplicación web que permita a trabajadores de un puesto de trabajo adjuntar su documentación (archivos) mediante un formulario. El problema es que al momento de presionar el submit del formulario con los archivos adjuntos, estos no se guardan, sin embargo, el nombre y otros campos de tipo `Charfield` sí se guardan correctamente. La única forma de que se guarden los archivos es adjuntarlos desde el portal de admin, pero la idea es que cada usuario ingrese desde una url generada con su id que se enviará por correo electrónico.  Además, los archivos se deberían guardar con la nomenclatura (DSR_”rut”-”nombre”-”nombre del archivo (label del formulario)”-0-”extensión), pero aún no logro configurar la nomenclatura de la instancia del nombre del archivo, según el label del formulario.

models.py es el siguiente:

```py
    class Candidato(models.Model):
       nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 70, null=True, blank=True)
       rut = models.CharField(max_length = 10, primary_key=True)
       correo = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
       centro_de_costo =models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length =30, choices = cc)
       estado = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
       imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_directory_name, null=True, blank=True)
       certificado_antecedentes = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_directory_name, null=True, blank=True)
       hoja_de_vida_conductor = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_directory_name, null=True, blank=True)
       certificado_residencia = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_directory_name, null=True, blank=True)
       certificado_afiliacion_afp = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_directory_name, null=True, blank=True)
       certificado_afiliacion_salud = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_directory_name, null=True, blank=True)
       fotocopia_cedula_identidad = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_directory_name, null=True, blank=True)
       fotocopia_licencia_conducir = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_directory_name, null=True, blank=True)
       curriculum_vitae = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_directory_name, null=True, blank=True)
       ultimo_finiquito = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_directory_name, null=True, blank=True)`

       class Meta:
           verbose_name="candidato"
           verbose_name_plural="candidatos"

       def __str__(self):
           return self.nombre +" "+ self.rut
```

El archivo debería subirse a upload_directory_name, pero como mencioné en el comienzo, aún me falta la instancia para el nombre del archivo, según el label:

```py
    def upload_directory_name(instance, filename):
       ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
       filename = "DSR_%s_%s_0.%s" % (instance.rut, instance.nombre , ext)
       return os.path.join('uploads',filename)
```

views.py

```py
    class CandidatoList(ListView):
       model = Candidato
       template_name = 'candidato/candidato_list.html'
       paginate_by = 2

    class CandidatoCreate(CreateView):
       model = Candidato
       form_class = Candidato_form
       template_name = 'candidato/candidato_form.html'
       success_url = 'https://www.google.cl/'

    class CandidatoUpdate(UpdateView):
       model = Candidato    
       form_class = Candidato_form
       template_name = 'candidato/candidato_form.html'
       success_url = 'https://www.google.cl/'
```

forms.py:

```py
    class Candidato_form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Candidato

        fields = [
            'nombre',
            'rut',
            'certificado_antecedentes',
            'hoja_de_vida_conductor',
            'certificado_residencia',
            'certificado_afiliacion_afp',
            'certificado_afiliacion_salud',
            'fotocopia_cedula_identidad',
            'fotocopia_licencia_conducir',
            'curriculum_vitae',
            'ultimo_finiquito',
        ]

        labels = {
            'nombre': 'Nombre',
            'rut': 'Rut',
            'certificado_antecedentes': 'Certificado Antecedentes',
            'hoja_de_vida_conductor': 'Hoja de vida del conductor',
            'certificado_residencia': 'Certificado de residencia',
            'certificado_afiliacion_afp': 'Certificado afiliación AFP',
            'certificado_afiliacion_salud': 'Certificado afiliacion de salud',
            'fotocopia_cedula_identidad': 'Fotocopia de cedula de identidad',
            'fotocopia_licencia_conducir': 'Fotocopia de licencia de conducir',
            'curriculum_vitae': 'Curriculum vitae',
            'ultimo_finiquito': 'Ultimo finiquito',
            
        }

        widgets = {
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'rut': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'certificado_antecedentes': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={"multiple":True, 'class':'form-control'}),
            'hoja_de_vida_conductor': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={"multiple":True, 'class':'form-control'}),
            'certificado_residencia': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={"multiple":True, 'class':'form-control'}),
            'certificado_afiliacion_afp': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={"multiple":True, 'class':'form-control'}),
            'certificado_afiliacion_salud': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={"multiple":True, 'class':'form-control'}),
            'fotocopia_cedula_identidad': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={"multiple":True, 'class':'form-control'}),
            'fotocopia_licencia_conducir': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={"multiple":True, 'class':'form-control'}),
            'curriculum_vitae': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={"multiple":True, 'class':'form-control'}),
            'ultimo_finiquito': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={"multiple":True, 'class':'form-control'}),
            
        }

        def clean_name(self):
            name = self.cleaned_data['nombre']
            if len(name) < 2:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Name must be at least 2 characters long.")
            return name

        def clean_id(self):
            id = self.cleaned_data['rut']
            if len(id) < 2:
                raise forms.ValidationError("ID must be at least 2 characters long.")
            return id

urls.py:

    from django.urls import path
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from candidato.views import CandidatoUpdate, CandidatoList, CandidatoCreate
    
    urlpatterns = [
      
    path("candidato_list/", CandidatoList.as_view(), name="candidato_list"),
    path("candidato_create/", CandidatoCreate.as_view(), name="candidato_create"),
    path("candidato_edit/<str:pk>/",CandidatoUpdate.as_view(), name="candidato_edit"),
     
   
    ]
    if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

La parte principal del block content del template del formulario:

```html
    <form method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{form.as_p}}
       <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
       <button type="reset" onclick="return confirmarReset()">Reiniciar</button>

    </form>
```